# Retrieve 'generic' data from non-templated interface

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

With the goal of creating a generic container for data, which allows me something like:

```
std::vector<GenericContainer> containerList = {"foo", 1.4f, 10, 'a'};
```

I have written the following code*:

```
struct GenericContainer
{
    template <typename DataType>
    GenericContainer(DataType && data) :
        _base(new Derived<DataType>(std::forward<DataType>(data)))
    { }

    // operates with the data
    void func()
    {    
        _base->func();
    }

    struct Base
    {
        virtual void func() = 0;
        virtual ~Base() = default;    
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Derived : public Base
    {
        Derived(T && data) :
            _data(std::forward<T>(data))
        {}

        void func() override
        {
            process(_data);
        }

        T _data;
    };
    Base * _base;
};
```

Here `process` can be a free function, conveniently defined for each type.

```
void process(const float& f) { /**/ } 
void process(const int& i) { /**/ } 
// ...
```

My question: **is there an *elegant* way of recovering the data from GenericContainer with its original type?** (without using things like `stringstream` to handle the data).

My guess is that it can be done by passing some kind of template `struct` of *functor* to `GenericContainer`, but I'm stuck at this point.

*The code is inspired by [this article](http://blog.biicode.com/about-non-intrusive-polymorphism/).

Comment: You could check how [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html) is implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C++ object that can store data of any type in a value-like context, and can get it out if you provide the exact same type, is similar to a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html).

`boost::any` is an example of type erasure, where you "forget" many details about a type and only remember certain operations.  In the case of `any`, that is copy, destroy and cast-back-to-same-type.

In your case, you have forgotten everything except `process` and destroy.

Run-time concepts is another name for this technique.

`boost::variant` is another approach, where it stores one of a list of types, and provides ways to "visit" the contained data.  Because it knows the list of types it stores, it can type-check function objects passed in, and ensure they can consume the type of every data stored.  Then at runtime it can pick which one to call.

---

In general, if you have RTTI enabled (many compilers give you the option to remove it), adding "cast-back-to-same-type" is relatively easy.  In your case, simply do a `dyanmic_cast` on the container to `Derived<T>`, then if that worked just get the `_data` contained in it.  Such casts should usually admit failure.

If you know the type (or a list of types) you expect to be there, this lets you get it back out.  If you do not know the type, you can only run code that you have erased at construction.  In theory, the type erased data could have come from a DLL written completely independently of the code you want to run on the type; and C++ does not ship a compiler with each executable.

As an aside, your `GenericContainer(DataType && data)` has a dangerous signature; you are doing forwarding references, so this can mean your `GenericContainer` could end up storing a reference to DataType.  Usually a type should be value-semantics or reference-semantics; having a type silently switch between them will result in unexpected behavior.

---

```
template<class T>
T* as() {
  auto* d = dynamic_cast<Derived<T>*>(_base);
  if (!d) return nullptr;
  return std::addressof(d->_data);
}
template<class T>
T const* as() const {
  auto const* d = dynamic_cast<Derived<T>*>(_base);
  if (!d) return nullptr;
  return std::addressof(d->_data);
}
```

the above methods would enable `GenericContainer c; int* i = c.as<int>();`, and `i` is nullptr iff c does not have an `int` in it.